# blur event not fired for dynamically created textbox

Tags: jquery

Is there a reason that blur event is activated for the first input. But for dynamically generated textbox it does not fire.

```
<input type="text" class="year" />
<div id="t"></div>

<script>
$('.year').blur(function () {
    $('#t').html('<input type="text" id="y" />');
});

$('#y').on('blur', function () {
    alert('hello');
});
</script>
```

> check on fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kynsai/6pfST/

**EDIT**

I am creating the input using the following code

```
<input type="text" id="rows" />
<div id="form"></div>



 $('#rows').on('blur', function () {
    msg = '<table"><tr><td>Year</td></tr>';
    for (i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++) {
        msg = msg + '<tr><td><input type="text" id="Year_' + i + '"></td></tr>';
    }
    msg = msg + '</table>';
    $('#form').html(msg);
});
```

so why does this line not work?

```
  $('input[id ^="Year_"]').on('blur', function () {
    alert('t');

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .on() (.live() is deprecated in new jQueries). And wrap it in document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('focusout','.year', function() {
       $('#t').html('<input type="text" id="y" />');
    }).on('focusout', '#y', function() {
       alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: your code works for this demo. But is there any reason why it didn't work on my previous code?

Comment: I think you're missing document ready function in your actual website (jsfiddle does not require it). Check my updated answer.

Comment: It is inside the document ready function. Is there something else i have to do to register the dynamically created textbox for an event to be fired?

Comment: Don't think so, if you're using the `.on()` method. If it works in the demo, my guess would be you've missed to update the selectors corresponding to your actual website (for example '#y' should be '#Year-something'). If that's not the case, I've no idea so far. :\

Comment: kindly check the fiddle site. I have updated exactly as written in my code... http://jsfiddle.net/kynsai/6pfST/14/

Comment: Thank you very much... Its firing now... :)

Answer (score 0):

try the following code... use live function

```
<script>
$('.year').live('blur',function () {
    $('#t').html('<input type="text" id="y" />');
});

</script>
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated, should suggest to use `on`

Answer (score 0):

Try put your blur event for `#y` inside the blur event for `.year` ,  as it outside  the event will not work probably as it wasn't yet put in your html so try this code:

```
$('.year').on('blur',function () {
    $('#t').html('<input type="text" id="y" />');

    $('#y').on('blur', function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```